# How to Select master table data and select referance table top one data sql query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, inner-join

i need an sql query which should return the master table entry and its child table entry (**the latest one entry only**). I used inner join for this. But i its not working fine.
Can anyone give a give me a proper query for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: pls refer the given link it might be useful to you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972286/getting-the-last-record-in-sql-in-where-condition

Comment: On what column sorting in the child table?

Comment: i need to select all the entries in master table and need to select its child entry(top one according to createdDate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLServer2005+ use option with [OUTER APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator

```
SELECT *
FROM master t1 OUTER APPLY (
                            SELECT TOP 1 t2.Col1, t2.Col2 ...
                            FROM child t2
                            WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id
                            ORDER BY t2.CreatedDate DESC
                            ) o
```

OR option with [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function

```
;WITH cte AS
 (                            
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.Id ORDER BY t2.CreatedDate DESC) AS rn
  FROM master t1 JOIN child t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT ID, DATE
(
SELECT M.ID, C.DATE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY M.ID ORDER BY C.DATE DESC) RN
FROM MASTER M
JOIN CHILD C
ON C.ID = M.ID
) A
WHERE RN = 1
```